# How can I repair my bathroom cabinet?

Tags: repair, bathroom, sink, mdf

I've got a [Medium-density fibreboard (MDF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-density_fibreboard) sink cabinet that is at least 30, if not 50 years old.  The bottom has gotten wet a few hundred times from a shower that was near it, and it is flaking apart at the bottom where it meets the linoleum.  It's also right by the laundry shoot, so it gets rubbed on a lot.  I'd like to patch it with something water resistant, then paint and sand the whole cabinet smooth.

What should I use for patching it?  Is there something more water resistant than wood putty?   It should be fine if a soaking wet towel gets thrown next to it and sits for 3-4 hours a dozen times.  I will yell at the kids, but I'm sure it's going to happen.

NOTE: I will probably sand off most if not all of the paint, so a thin coat of whatever on the paint or the MDF should be fine.

Comment: Probably only 30 since MDF didn't come into widespread usage until the 1980s.

Comment: MDF is the paper woven board right? Is there a different type of material that is flaky?

Comment: Fibreboard is a low density composite that has a woven quality.  Wood chips in a flaky random pattern is often called particleboard. MDF is a fairly dense smooth cocoa brown board with no significant texture or color variations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want an epoxy based filler such as [Bondo](http://bondo.com/products/household/bondo-wood-filler-20082.html).  A variety of manufacturers have a version of this.

These products are a little more complicated to use than traditional wood fillers, but they are pretty impervious to moisture once they harden.  You need to mix small batches that can be used in a few minutes. Nitrile/latex gloves are a must.

Once done, better than wood or MDF for durablility.

Comment: +vote for Bondo.   Bondo is great for repairs in this type of situation or outdoor trim. It can be a little difficult to use and shape/sand, but once you get the hang of it, it is a great water resistant filler.